# regex adding a only finding 4 numbers if they have a '-' next to it

Tags: php, regex

We have url's which look like this
`http://www.example.co.uk/example-product-3436.html` I want to be able to use a php script which will delete the `-unqiue number` . I am going to use regex to do this. I have found this `([^\d])[0-9]{4}` which will find any four digit number, but I only want it to find a 4 digit number if it has a `-` in front of it. How can I do this?

Comment: [`-(\d{4})\.html`](https://regex101.com/r/pB1rL2/2)

Comment: [`-([0-9]{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/aH9rB5/1)

Comment: Its because OP has already stated _it to find a 4 digit number if it has a - in front of it._ @Tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just a minor change to your regex:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.co.uk/example-product-3436.html';

if(preg_match('/-[0-9]{4}/', $url, $matches)) {
    $cleanUrl = str_replace($matches[0], '', $url);
}

echo $cleanUrl;
```

Comment: Instead you can simply use `echo preg_replace('/-[0-9]{4}/','',$url);`

Comment: Thank you! So if I added a `/g` like this `/-[0-9]{4}/g` then it would do it gloably? say if I had a whole .txt file to this with?

Answer (score 3):

```
//Regular expression
$regex = "/-(\\d{4})\\.html/";

//String to check
$string = "http://www.example.co.uk/example-product-3436.html"; 

//Output match to $match
preg_match($regex, $string, $match);

//Print the unique number
echo $match[1];
```

---

Explanation of the regular expression:

1. `/` is the start of the regex
2. `-` matches a hyphen character
3. `(...)` is a capturing group (what you want to return)
4. `\d` matches any digit ([0-9])
5. `{4}` requires exact four characters (`\d{4}` requires exact four digits)
6. `\.` matches the character "." literally
7. `html` matches "html" literally
8. `/` marks the end of the regex

Answer (score 2):

To replace the 4 digits preceded by a hyphen and if followed by `.html` use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$str = preg_replace('/-\d{4}(?=\.html)/', "", $str);
```

- `-\d{4}` matches a hyphen followed by 4 digits
- `(?=\.html)/` looks if `.html` is ahead

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/518811)

Without also delimiting to the right `\d{4}` would match [within numbers of any length >= 4](https://regex101.com/r/bM7nF7/1).
You can also use a `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to the right if this is sufficient for your input.